# Order of indices using index notation

Tags: classical-mechanics, index-notation

I'm trying to solve a problem in Lagrangian mechanics involving index notation. I'm wondering if the expression
$$ A_{ij}\dot{q^i}q^j = A_{ji}\dot{q^j}q^i $$
is true. Our professor skipped over this notation convention and I think the problem is made much easier if it is true.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have trouble thinking about this sort of thing, take it in stages:

$$A_{ij}\dot{q}^iq^j=A_{kl}\dot{q}^kq^l=A_{ji}\dot{q}^jq^i,$$where at the first equals I impose $i,\,j\mapsto k,\,l$ while at the second I impose $k,\,l\mapsto j,\,i$.

Comment: Cool thank you! Now that you say it it seems nearly obvious. I think the fact that it's assumed we should already be familiar with the convention despite having never seen it before has caught me off-guard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the same. Indices don't carry any meaning, they are just labels. As an example

$$
\sum_i a_i b^i = \sum_p a_p b^p
$$

or in Einstein's notation

$$
a_i b^i = a_p b^p
$$

So, coming back to your example

$$
A_{ij}\dot{q}^i q^j = A_{m n}\dot{q}^m q^n = A_{j i}\dot{q}^j q^i
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help!